# Ajax in Wordpress plugin

Tags: ajax, plugins, wordpress

I am creating a simple wordpress plugin and trying to use AJAX, but I always get 0 in ajax response.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var data = {
    action: 'my_action',
    whatever: '1234'
};


jQuery.post("http://localhost/taichi/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", data,   function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
});
 </script>
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' ); 




function my_action_callback() {

echo "test";
die();

}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you [Why is my ajax request getting response 0?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19371705/3248921

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the add_action at the complete bottom of your file or else it won't find the callback function

Answer (score 1):

Try to change :

```
jQuery.post("http://localhost/taichi/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", data,   function(response)
```

To :

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response)
```

And check if it is working on the admin side first. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Error Return Values**

If the AJAX request fails when the request url is wp-admin/admin-ajax.php, it will return either `-1 or 0` depending on the reason it failed.

[Read this](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Edit

[admin-ajax](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php) always return default '0' as output.so while you alerting response you will `0 only`.using `die()` in callback function will terminate that.

Comment: but why is it failing? is there any way to figure it out?

Comment: I am using die(); in callback function
------> 
    function my_action_callback() {
    echo "test";
    die();
    }

Comment: maybe my callback function is not being called for some reason. I tried using this code in my plugin and on my theme's index.php file but no luck.

Comment: @Waqar: Similar problem here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-ajax-call-to-wp-ajaxphp-in-admin-page-returning-0 . he use some numeric at the end of callback,But i am not sure

Comment: I tried that as well but no luck but thanks for sending the link.

Comment: Using `die` just results in nothing being returned, not a proper return value.

Comment: Profk, try using die($returnSomething); The example is not very straight forward, is there a way to debug or return a reason why it's failing?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, it turned out that my callback was inside a php file which was only included to my "Theme Options" page.

To check if the function is able to trigger trougth admin-ajax.php try to add `var_dump(function_exists("your_callback_name"));` to the bottom of the wp-admin/admin-ajax.php (before `die( '0' );`) and then have a look to your ajax output.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code in your plugin file. or in function.php

```
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var ajaxURL = 'http://localhost/taichi/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
    var dataString = 'action=mnd_news';
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxURL,
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
    if(response != 'error') {
    alert(response);
    }
    }
    });
    });
    
    add_action('wp_ajax_mnd_news', 'get_mnd_ajax');
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_mnd_news', 'get_mnd_ajax' ); 
    function get_mnd_ajax() {
    echo "test";
    die();
    }
```