# Wordpress AJAX in plugin response 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I create plugin for Wordpress and use AJAX in plugin but AJAX response 0. I try to solve this problem by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19371705/3248921) but can't solve my problem.

This is my handler function

```
if( is_admin())  {
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'language_redirect_add_config_page' );
}
else {
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'preference_language' );
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_preference_language', 'preference_language' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_preference_language', 'preference_language' );
}

function language_redirect_config_page() {
    add_options_page( __( 'Language Redirect Setting' ), __( 'Language Redirect' ), 'manage_options', basename( __FILE__ ), '' );
}

function enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/js/plugin-script.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
        ) 
    );
}

// Handler function...
function preference_language() {
    $language = $_POST['language'];
    if($language == 'th') {
        header( 'Location: ' . site_url('th') );
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
    die;
}
```

And this my AJAX script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var language = localStorage.getItem('language');
    var data = {
        action: 'preference_language',
        language: language
    };
    $.post(
        ajax_object.ajax_url, 
        data, 
        function(response) {
            console.log(response);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the

```
die;
```

with

```
exit;
```

the 0 error is a default error in wordpress for ajax most of the time it is die; will break everything. hope this helps

Comment: I replacing **die;** with **exit;** but still get response 0

Answer (score 0):

```
 header( 'Location: ' . site_url('th') );
```

You can't set headers after output has been rendered. Remember ajax is called from the frontend and obviously output has already started.

heres an way of doing this (untested):

```
function preference_language() {
      $language = $_POST['language'];
      if($language == 'th') {
        echo site_url('th');
      } else {
        return;
      }
   exit;
}
```

js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var language = localStorage.getItem('language');
    var data = {
        action: 'preference_language',
        language: language
    };
    $.post(
        ajax_object.ajax_url, 
        data, 
        function(response) {
            window.location = response;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you quite sure that

```
 localStorage.getItem('language')
```

actually holds a value that is or could be 'th'?

To be sure that your code works you could use the following code instead of your current preference_language():

```
function preference_language() {
    $language = $_POST['language'];
    if($language == 'th') {
        echo "language is th.";
    }
    else {
        echo "language is not th.";
    }
    die;
}
```